Data structure help in python
I am learning about using algorithms and data structures for my class. I'm having some problems with a lab about stacks. I'm running into an issue with my InsertAtCommand object, its supposed to go through a stack, remove at a certain index and then undo what was removed back to same index. So far I think I might have figured out that it seems to not be inserting the last item when it goes through since I have 2 tests that are failing because they are missing one item even though they have a different number of items in the list. I'm just not sure what could be wrong and would really appreciate any pointers. I've attached the github link with the repository, it includes 3 text files with failing outputs so you can see what it is testing for, and the prompt of the lab. I am new to python and still trying to find my bearings so go easy haha.
Here is the github link to view all of the files: https://github.com/vitodorado/Stacks-Lab-
I have since reverted my change back the original statement.
I have tried changing the undo statement in the undo object in the InsertAtCommand.py file
from:
def undo(self):
    del self.source_list\[self.index\]

to:
def undo(self):
    print("Before undo - List:", self.source_list)
    print("Before undo - Removed item:", self.removed_item)
    #remove the new item that was inserted during the execute method
    self.source_list.pop(self.index)
    #reinsert the previously removed item at the original index
    self.source_list.insert(self.index, self.removed_item)
    print("After undo - List:", self.source_list)

but I for some reason got the same output of:
Adding chips
PASS: Undo stack size is 1
Adding cookies
PASS: Undo stack size is 2
Adding waffles
PASS: Undo stack size is 3
Adding syrup
PASS: Undo stack size is 4
Adding ice cream
PASS: Undo stack size is 5
Adding lettuce
PASS: Undo stack size is 6
Verfied list content: chips,cookies,waffles,syrup,ice cream,lettuce
Removing at index 2
PASS: Undo stack size is 7
Verfied list content: chips,cookies,syrup,ice cream,lettuce
Removing at index 2
PASS: Undo stack size is 8
Verfied list content: chips,cookies,ice cream,lettuce
Removing at index 3
PASS: Undo stack size is 9
Verfied list content: chips,cookies,ice cream
Removing at index 0
PASS: Undo stack size is 10
Verfied list content: cookies,ice cream
Executing undo
PASS: Undo stack size is 9
FAIL:
        Expected items: ['chips', 'cookies', 'ice cream']
        Actual items:   ['cookies', 'ice cream']

This is the code in question:
class InsertAtCommand(UndoCommand):
    def __init__(self, source, index, new_item):
        super().__init__()
        self.source_list = source
        self.index = index
        self.new_item = new_item
        self.removed_item = None
    

    def execute(self):
    
        #remove the item at the specified index and store it 
        self.removed_item = self.source_list.pop(self.index)
        #Insert the new item at the specified index
        self.source_list.insert(self.index, self.new_item)   

    def undo(self):
        #remove the new item that was inserted during the execute 
        #method
        self.source_list.pop(self.index)
        #reinsert the previously removed item at the original index
        self.source_list.insert(self.index, self.removed_item)

And this is what calls it:
def remove_at_with_undo(self, removal_index):
        #check if index is valid
        if 0 <= removal_index < len(self.list_items):
            #store the removed item
            removed_item = self.list_items[removal_index]
            #remove the item at the specified index
            del self.list_items[removal_index]

        #push an InsertAtCommnad onto the undo stack to undo the 
        removal
            insert_command = InsertAtCommand(self.list_items[:], 
            removal_index, removed_item)
            self.undo_stack.push(insert_command)

this also calls it:
def execute_undo(self):
       if self.undo_stack:
       #pop the last command from the undo stack
           undo_command = self.undo_stack.pop()
        #Check if the undo command is an instance of 
RemoveLastCommand
           if isinstance(undo_command, RemoveLastCommand):
           #execute the undo command
               undo_command.execute()
           elif isinstance(undo_command, SwapCommand):
               undo_command.undo()
           elif isinstance(undo_command, InsertAtCommand):
               undo_command.undo()


Post all your related codes in your question.

What is the goal of the class teaching you about stacks? May you provide a minimal code example of the issue you are experiencing in the question listing what you are getting and what you expect to get?

Please read [mcve]

Here is the github link Nobody is going to dig through github to solve your problem.  It's your job to post a short but complete code example right here in the question.

I have added edited the post to have the code in question. The question basically wants you to do an action and then undo the action. The part I am stuck on is the removal at a certain index and then undoing the removal. I have added the output I am getting and the expected output.
